# oracle apex timestamp interval with sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

hi here i have a problem, i want to remove the expired entry from the table so I used the SQL where clause 
here is my SQL code

```
select ROWID,
       FOOD_RECEIVED_UID,
       USER_NAME,
       ITEM_TYPE,
       ITEM,
       QUANTITY,
       EXPIRY_DATE,
       CREATED_ON,
       CREATED_BY,
       UPDATED_ON,
       UPDATED_BY,
       USER_UID
  from FOOD_RECEIVED
   WHERE (ITEM_TYPE = :P9_ITEM_TYPE OR :P9_ITEM_TYPE IS NULL)and EXPIRY_DATE > SYSTIMESTAMP
```

Here is the photo copy:

[image: here is the photo copy]

could anyone help me to fix this...

Comment: Please detail: do you have an error message ? What is the expected output ? Please avoid to post pictures but instead post just plan text.

Comment: zero error, i want the report to  be displayed with the **where** clause the expired food should not be displayed in the report

Answer (score 0):

Aren't expired products those whose `expiry_date` has already passed? `<`, not `>`.

```
and EXPIRY_DATE < SYSTIMESTAMP
```

Though, I doubt that `expiry_date` is a timestamp; looks more like a `date`, so:

```
and EXPIRY_DATE < SYSDATE
```

Comment: the reason why I used the '''SYSTIMESTAMP''' is the expired_date is represented in time i have changed  the formate could you help me to fix this

Comment: In Oracle DATE datatype contains both date **and** time, so - SYSDATE it is. I don't know what would you want me to "fix". If you posted test case (CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO and expected output), then I/we could assist further. Until then, I'd say that what I already wrote fits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear to me what kind of solution you're looking for.

1. Do you want a SQL statement which removes all of the expired items in once?

   In that case, convert the select statement into a delete statement `delete from FOOD_RECEIVED where ....`
2. Do you want a delete button in your report to remove them individually?

   Did you try to use the the APEX wizard to create the page? **Create a Page** -> **Report** -> **Report with Form**. Using that, APEX will create a modal dialog for you where you can delete the individual items.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't want the expired items  to be displayed in that report if I use delete then it will delete from the table so could you suggest me a better option

Comment: In the results above, the report doesn't show expired items. The products you see have an expiry date in the future, at the time of query execution. Exactly what you described as 'wanted'..